# restarted computer and got: ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been having some issues with gulp serving my files so I restarted my computer, upon going back to my project and starting the server I suddenly got the error: `ImportError: No module named django.core.management`.

I am working locally and in my files I can see the django folder - it's path is: `MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django`

The full error looks like this:

```
    Message:
    Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Details:
    killed: false
    code: 1
    signal: null
    cmd: /bin/sh -c ./manage.py runserver
    stdout: 
    stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

My manage.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tckt.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

running which python gives me this:
`/usr/bin/python`

I am not sure if I am running in a virtual enviornment or not. I am doing the front-end of this project, the enviornment was set up and installed by someone else for me - but running `python -c 'import sys; print sys.real_prefix' 2>/dev/null && INVENV=1 || INVENV=0` (as another post suggested to check if I was in a virtual enviornment) returned nothing.

I have looked through some of the other posts and see that some people have reinstalled, others have modified paths, others say NOT to edit the manage.py file  - but since I am not really sure if the problem is the path or the install I am not sure how to proceed.If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing python packages which means you're [VirtualEnv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) isn't activated.

[VirtualEnv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) creates a folder named `env` by default (though the name can be changed) which is where it stores the specific python installation and all it's packages. Search for the `activate` bash script in your project folder.  Once you locate you can source it.

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

In the interest of completeness, in Windows it would be a batch file.

```
env/bin/activate.bat
```

You'll know you're in a virtualenv when your command prompt is prefixed by the env name, for example `(env) Macbook user$`.

You can now start your django test server.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

To deactivate, simply type `deactivate` at any time in your command prompt. The `(env)` prefix on the prompt should disappear.

Comment: oh that's interesting, prior to restarting my computer my prompt was prefixed by a folder name (I don't remember which one) - awesome I will go check for that `activate` script...will it be in a specific file?

Comment: That folder name, if it was surrounded by parenthesis `(env)` is your virtual environment. the `activate` script will be located in that folder in a `bin` folder. Typically, `env/bin/activate`.

Comment: i see `scripts/bin` and inside of that there is only one file called 'create-database`, perhaps it somehow got deleted... should I manually recreate it?

Comment: That's unrelated. I strongly recommend reading through the virtualenv docs so you have a better idea of the folder structure it creates, so you know what to look for on your hard drive. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: No problem. Be sure to post back here when you find it. You could also try searching the file system for `activate_this.py` since that's one of the other files that's always included in the environment as well.  `sudo find / -name "activate_this.py` should do a full file system search.

Comment: will do (posting back here later).  I ran sudo find / -name "activate_this.py which returned nothing just gave me a different prompt, so I exited out of it and went to python env thinking maybe that's where i should run it from...got nothing. Also a file search, from my root,  for `activate_this.py` returned nothing. I suspect something got deleted, it was def there before, and since yesterday I have been having weird issues with files being deleted. I will check out the link and get more info

Comment: So I see that my path should have looked more like 'ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django` but being that it does not, I am still unclear as to what I should DO about it. Running `virtualenv --version` in terminal returns `15.0.2` so it seems to be installed, with missing folders/files. The activate file just does not seem to exist anywhere on my hard drive. It is entirely possible it got deleted somehow, as I mentioned - things went pretty haywire on me yesterday. So I am still at square one with this. Do I reinstall? How do I fix this if there is no activate file?

Comment: That's very strange that they're missing. You could create a new environment called "TEMP" or something then copy the files from `TEMP/bin/` across to your `ENV/bin/` to get them back.